# React inputs aren't rendering properly after value change when the keys are the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

https://codesandbox.io/embed/trusting-fire-bz5ti

here is a code sandbox showing the issue

in the working version I have used Math.random() as the key

in the not working version I have used the index of the array as the key

when the array this.state.values updates it re renders the collection of inputs, however because they have the same key value it appears that it doesn't update the values properly.

you can try this by adding values (a, b, c, d) into each new input that appears and then deleting b or c to view the behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I feel kinda lazy to write the answer so will point you to this article (which has a nice sample demo'ing the issue) - https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318 The gist is that, React tracks list items by "key" and when you use the index as a "key", it works unpredictably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Sung M. Kim said basically needed to provide each element of the array with a consistent key. I did this by including a key value in the object inputs object.

https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318